# Travis CI - Build a dynamic matrix with git

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, integration-testing, travis-ci

I currently have a matrix for travis ci that includes over 150 tests. The scope of the project is such that if any of the files within these test directories are changed, travis will run that test. How this works is we run a script that performs a complicated `git diff` for every test, determines if the full test needs to be run for that entry in the matrix, and if not it exits and moves to the next matrix entry. These 150+ tests are listed line by line in the matrix and it's time expensive to iterate over each, run the diff, and determine if the test needs to be run at all.

A solution would be to build the matrix in advance based on our git diffing script such that all tests listed in the matrix would be exactly all the tests that need to be run. The travis folks don't seem to have a way to do this. Are there reasonable solutions to this problem that don't include iterating over every possible test? Or other free continuous-integration tools for open source projects that offer a solution to this?

Comment: The matrix size must be known at compile-time, but you might just run all tests regardless of whether they changed, right? Can you include repo/job link?

Comment: No, running all tests is only warranted under certain conditions and can take up to a full day. We have partially solved this by hitting each test and then early exiting, but I was hoping for an even better strategy. I have some ideas on this. https://github.com/techempower/FrameworkBenchmarks